# Skyrim does not detect AMD Radeon graphics

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, graphics-card

I have been playing Skyrim for about a week and today I realized that Skyrim uses the Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 adapter instead of the AMD Radeon (TM) R5 M335. My laptop has two graphics cards, one Intel and one Radeon, and it is supposed to switch between them when required. For some reason though, it seems that Skyrim cannot detect the Radeon graphics card... I tried googling the issue but none of the suggestions resolved my issue.

**Edit:** I run Skyrim on a Dell Inspiron 5559 64bit, if that helps

Comment: whats the brand and model of your laptop?>

Comment: @ZeroStack I edited my question including the brand and model of my laptop

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a problem with the game.

There should be a configuration on your computer that lets you set which adapter to use.  I have a Dell with nVidia graphics card and some games are set to the integrated Intel adapter instead of the more powerful nVidia one.

I currently do not have access to my laptop.  I will update my answer when the information is available.

Comment: Yep, it's not the game that chooses the card, it's the operating system.